# Cursor mapping and for each not working, mongodb & mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cursor, mongoose

I'm trying to find all documents in a collection with a field thats an array with an element that matches a certain parameter from a request. Ive trued the following but neither method seems to work. I'm using node mongodb and mongoose.

```
var cursor = db.Item.find({ cats: { $elemMatch: req.params.cat}});
cursor.map( function(myDoc) {console.log("myDoc.name: " + myDoc.name)});

var cursor = db.Item.find({ cats: { $elemMatch: req.params.cat}});
cursor.foreach( function(myDoc) {console.log("myDoc.name: " + myDoc.name)});
```

The error I am getting is Object # has no method 'forEach'.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: is req.params.cat an object? it has to be an object.

Comment: Its a string (not my choice), is there a good way in to make it an object instead?

Comment: the documentation says is has to be an object. If its a string then why do you wanna use elemmatch anyway? will { cats:  req.params.cat} alone work ?

Comment: My belief was that $elemMatch was needed for an array. Which is what cats is. I'm trying get all of the documents where at least one element in cats matchs req.params.cat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here considering you are using Mongoose. You seem to be trying to use the "shell" type syntax, but in mongoose you work of the model definitions

```
var itemSchema = new Schema({
    cats: []
});

var Item = mongoose.model( "Item", itemSchema );
```

And presuming then that your "cats" array only contains strings such as:

```
{
    "cats": [ "fluffy", "mittens", "stripes" ]
}
```

Then you issue the query from the "model" object and use the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator for matching the selection. Also as this is "node" the results are within a callback and not returned as a "left side" result:

```
Item.find({ "cats": { "$in": [req.params.cat] } },function(err,cats) {
    if ( err ) throw err; // handle errors in some way

    console.log( JSON.stringify( cats, undefined, 4 ) );
});
```

That will simply dump out all results as it is "automagically" transformed into an array. You can of course then use array iterators and transformers just as `.forEach()` or `.map()` on the result from here.

Comment: Thanks! Getting this error though: { "$err" : "invalid query", "code" : 12580 }. I'm having a hard time finding anything helpful online about it. All I can tell is that it has something to do with the "$in".

Comment: @Bren Yes. my bad, forgot the brackets `[]` around the argument to `$in`, which takes an array of possible matches.

Comment: That works! I had to change the stringify params to just cats. It complained that undefined was undefined. I'm going accept your answer.